# EnumProcessModules returns 0 with error 299

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm currently trying to enumerate all the modules of a supsended 32-bits process I've previously created from my 32-bits program, my Windows is 64-bits.
(I've already read all the other topics on that problem).

Here is the code:

```
let a = CreateProcessA(
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GlassWire\\GlassWire.exe\0".as_ptr(),
    null_mut(), null_mut(), null_mut(),
    false,
    0x00000004,
    null_mut(), null_mut(), SI, PI);
println!("{}", GetLastError());

let mut buffer: [*mut c_void;10] = [0 as *mut c_void;10];
WaitForInputIdle((*PI).hProcess as *mut c_void, -1);
let result = EnumProcessModules(
    (*PI).hProcess as *mut c_void,
    buffer.as_ptr() as *mut c_void,
    10, null_mut());

println!("EnumProcessModules([...]) = {} - {}", result, GetLastError());

let mut index: usize = 0x0; 
let mut modname: [u8;1024] = [0;1024];
while(transmute::<*mut c_void, u32>(buffer[index]) != 0x0){
    GetModuleFileNameExA((*PI).hProcess as *mut c_void, buffer[index], modname.as_ptr() as *mut c_void, 1024);
    println!("module: {}", std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&modname));
    modname = [0;1024];
    index += 1;
}
println!("Dump: {:?}", buffer.to_vec());
```

I saw that I had to use `WaitForInputIdle()` after using CreateProcessA before enumerating modules because the process doesn't have the time to "initialize", well when I do that, whatever the process I create (it successfully creates it) the program wait forever.

And when I try to do the same on the main process by replacing all the (*PI).hProcess by `GetCurrentProcess()` (I removed the `WintForInputIdle()` line), `EnumProcessModules()` still returns 0 but now `GetLastError()` returns 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS), **but** the modules handles are successfully written in `buffer`.

So the program output:

```
A:\Encrypted\Temp\injector\target\i686-pc-windows-msvc\debug\main.exe // (the program)
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Dump: [0x920000, 0x77180000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]
```

And if I specify the path of the running program in `CreateProcessA()`, it will also return 0 with 299 as the windows error code.

I'm really confused...Thanks for reading, I hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: `0x00000004` means `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, your new process is created with its thread in a suspended state, and then you wait forever for the new process to go idle. It's not going to go idle while it's suspended.

Comment: Likewise, If the module list in the target process is corrupted or not yet initialized, `EnumProcessModules` may fail with 299.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` instead of `CREATE_SUSPENDED(0x00000004)`, as @Jonathan Potter, the suspend state will block the function `WaitForInputIdle`.

Second, make sure that the process is not a console application or has a message queue, otherwise `WaitForInputIdle` returns immediately.

Then, you can try to call `SuspendThread` after `WaitForInputIdle` to suspend the process to prevent it from ending.

EDIT:

Pay attention to the last two parameters of [`EnumProcessModules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules#parameters):

`cb`

> The size of the lphModule array, **in bytes**.

`lpcbNeeded`

> The number of bytes required to store all module handles in the
>   lphModule array.

Here is a good sample on msdn: [Enumerating All Modules For a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process). Just replace `hProcess`.

Comment: Thanks it worked but it did the same that when I set `GetCurrentProcess()`, the main process and ntdll modules handles are wrote in buffer but the `EnumProcessModules()` still returns 0 and `GetLastError()` returns 998 (ERROR_NOACCESS -> Invalid access to memory location). What can I do to solve that ?

Comment: Note the last two parameters of [`EnumProcessModules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules#parameters),
`cb`: The size of the lphModule array, **in bytes.**(Not array size)
`lpcbNeeded`: The number of bytes required to store all module handles in the lphModule array.(can not be NULL, which will cause null pointer access violation exception in C/C++ code)

Comment: This may be because in 32-bit, `HMODULE` takes up 4 bytes, and 10 bytes can only get up to two `HMODULE`s(which you have got).